# Scalling an object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new in unity and in C# in general.

I was trying to make an animation with scale of a rectangle where it's getting bigger and smaller with time. I tried to use the statement `transform.localScale` but I didn't know how to make it with time, like a loop. So it gets big and small in a time frame of the 30s for example.

```
cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float TotalTime;
float Scale = 1;
GameObject Target;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Target = this.gameObject;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    TotalTime += Time.deltaTime;
    if (TotalTime < 30)
    {
        Scale += 0.01f;
        Target.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * Scale;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).